# ASP.NET MVC Authorisation with CRUD roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need the ability to restrict what users can do in my application based on dynamic roles for **CRUD**.

For example the User/Index would need an authentication such as `[ClaimsAuthorize("View", "User")]` as oposed to `[Authorise(Roles="Administrator")]` so that I can check if the user has the security to view.

I have the user roles configured, but what the roles enable users to do is dynamic. An administrator can change the security levels with check boxes that will enable different security groups to do different things.

The main problem is doing this in **Razor**, I need something similar to `@User.CanEditUsers`, but I am not sure how I can go about doing this at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am having trouble finding the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Authorizing users to see specific page elements differs from Authorizing for CRUD or other database operations, unless the elements point to operational Actions in Controller. Consider that you may have some elements that there's no need to be saw by a specific user, and don't have specific database operation. Till now we conclude that we need the following permissions :

1. Permission to See
2. Permission to Command

I believe that you can use [Microsoft Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for both parts. According to MSDN Documentation Considering that :

> The Authorize attribute lets you indicate that authorization is
>   restricted to predefined roles or to individual users.  This gives you
>   a high degree of control over who is authorized to view any page on
>   the site.

In The next step/question is how to do that?

I think 3 ways are available to meet our purpose:

- **Solution 1:** Creating separate Views with specific page elements due to forwarding each user to related View. In this scenario we must
  create separate controller actions too. we have to check user types
  before each action like `[Authorise(Roles="Administrator")]`. We
  forced to have static (Pre-defined) Roles and Accessibility. And in
  one sentence **Not a good solution because of redundancy and
  instability**.
- **Solution 2:** Creating pages Dynamically simply by adding some `if` conditions for each access restricted element in **One Page**(for
  example Edit Page). That is like employing `@if
  (User.IsInRole("Admin"))` to authorize specific users and show
  related page elements like buttons. In Controller side we can use
  `if` conditions (not as `FilterAttribute` due to add dynamic
  functionality based on generated/added new roles) and control valid
  transactions against database. Although `FilterAttribute`s add some great functionalists (like performance optimization). In one sentence **A moderate solution**.
- **Solution 3:** Act like solution 2, just fix Controller problem by
  creating our own custom FilterAttribute for authorization. That will
  inherited from `AuthorizeAttribute` and overrides the `OnAuthorize`
  method to do what you need **only for Operations**.

For Example :

```
public class TableAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public enum TableAction
    {
        Read,
        Create,
        Update,
        Delete
    }
    public TableAction Action { get; set; }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        //do custom authorizization using Action and getting TableEntryID 
        //from filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString or
        //filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form
    }
}
```

And its usage will be like this :

```
[TableAuthorize(Action=TableAuthorizeAttribute.TableAction.Update)]
```

[Here](http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2009/11/mvc-custom-authorization.html) is complete example about above concept. Here is complete example for creating dynamic `AuthorizeAttribute` for authorizing new roles added to application.

Solution 3 in one sentence **A perfect but Complex Solution**.

**Note that by using `FilterAttribute` before Actions we have limited our application to static/predefined roles.** No need to use another Data Structure or generate tables in Database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the concept of roles from groups in your design.

A role gives fixed permissions to perform certain actions in your application. A group is a set of users. What your administrator is really doing is to assign groups of users to different roles.

Your authorization code should be able to rely on fixed roles, e.g. an "ViewUserInfo" role. Then implement the administration interface so that when the admin enables a user to view userinfo, you add that user to the "ViewUserInfo" role.

The same goes with groups: If an entire user group is granted the right to view user info you should add that group to the "ViewUserInfo" role. To introduce the concept of groups and be able to add groups to roles you can't rely on the standard SimpleRoleProvider, so you probably have to implement your own role provider as well as a group provider.

In the end some workaround might be easier, but this is, in my opinion a cleaner architecture.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know if there are any examples of other developers trying to achieve a similar thing?

Answer (score 1):

From the horse's mouth: "Role management helps you manage authorization, which enables you to specify the resources that users in your application are allowed to access. Role management lets you treat groups of users as a unit by assigning users to roles such as manager, sales, member, and so on." (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Users can be in multiple roles, and you can leverage action filters to get fine-grained control of access to the various resources in your site:

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Contributor, Designer, Reviewer")]
```

I think the "dynamic" aspect you are after revolves around Administrators being able to add and remove users on-demand from the roles which provide access to those resources, which is pretty typical.

The idea of constantly changing the permissions your roles grant would be a bad design choice.